# CASE in MySQL forces column datatype to BIGINT instead of INT

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, mysql-workbench

Well it would rather be a very simple thing but I couldn't figure out myself.

While trying the below line in Stored Procedure in MYSQL server, it converts or sets the column datatype to BIGINT instead of expected INT

```
CASE `L`.`Code` WHEN 'ABCD' THEN 0 ELSE `XL`.`ID` END as XLID
```

The magical thing is that if I remove the 0 from it, then it returns INT as datatype as expected. So this 0 is to blame for sure, but I couldn't understand why and how to resolve this? I tried to use CAST but it didn't allow to cast INT to INT.

[image: This trick also didn't work]

Would be a great help.

Comment: Try: ``CASE `L`.`Code` WHEN 'ABCD' THEN CAST('0' AS UNSIGNED) ELSE `XL`.`ID` END AS XLID``

Comment: @wchiquito: thanks but nope, still the same BIGINT :-(

Comment: Maybe it's MySQL Workbench who do the conversion.

Comment: @wchiquito: yes I suspect the same, looking into it now, but well still it's weird. The problem is, I am having trouble at the application side, unless I specifically mention it as Int64 in C#, it gives InvalidCastException.

Comment: Then the problem is not MySQL Workbench.

Comment: Check: [Connector returning Long instead of Int](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=64084).

Comment: @wchiquito: Ohh interesting, let me have a detailed look first, will post if I find a solution or reasoning for this. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The following trick can help:

```sql
DELIMITER //

CREATE FUNCTION `return_integer`(`number` INT UNSIGNED)
RETURNS INT UNSIGNED DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
    RETURN `number`;
END//

DELIMITER ;

SELECT
    CASE `L`.`Code`
       WHEN 'ABCD' THEN `return_integer`(0)
       ELSE `L`.`ID`
    END AS XLID
FROM `table_name` `L`;
```