# Force BigInt to be INTEGER in a view

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, view

I have an Alarm table that has column for device, severity and an obsolete flag among others and view that is generating one of it's columns in a CASE statement.  The idea is that many alarms for the same device will be grouped together and their overallSeverity will either be the maximum severity of not obsolete alarms or will be the lowest possible severity (1) if they are all flagged obsolete.

Here is what I'm trying:

```
(CASE
    WHEN (SUM(`al`.`OBSOLETE`) = COUNT(`al`.`ALARM_ID`)) THEN 1
    ELSE (SELECT 
            MAX(`al`.`SEVERITY`)
        FROM
            `alarm` `al`
        WHERE
            (`al`.`OBSOLETE` <> 1))
END) AS `overallSeverity`,
```

Which works fine as sql and gives the desired result in MySQL Workbench

The issue is that I'm using hibernate to select from this view and show these groups on a webpage and the Java code is expecting overallSeverity to be an int and SQL seems to default it to be a BigInt.

The following worked but doesnt always return the desired value for overallSeverity if none of them were actually the lowest possible value:

```
WHEN SUM(al.OBSOLETE) = COUNT(al.ALARM_ID) THEN min(al.severity)
```

In this case if the lowest severity in the group was 2 then that's of course what is returned as overallSeverity but if all are obsolete we want to always display 1.

Is there a way to force the view to return an INTEGER for that column?  The severity column in Alarm is type int(1) so I'm essentially trying to keep that.

Comment: I circumvented this by changing the @Column annotation's colunmDefinition from "INTEGER" to "bigint" and Java seems fine with converting it to an int.  

I'm going to leave this question open however because I find the behavior or SQL strange, why is it switching the column type from int(1) to bigint?

Comment: Check: [CASE in MySQL forces column datatype to BIGINT instead of INT](http://stackoverflow.com/q/27907817/1316440).